# Why `systemctl list-unit-files` command output does not contain logstash

Tags: logstash, systemd, elastic-stack, sysv

I Installed ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana) with YUM onto our centos based system and set them as start at boot time. Then When I tried command `systemctl list-unit-files`, the output only contains Kibana and Elasticsearch without Logstash at all. But Logstash is indeed listed in command `chkconfig --list`

According to my understanding, it means that Logstash is a `SysV` service, whereas Kibana and Elasticsearch are `systemd` services. Is it so? If so why is Logstash different from Elasticsearch and Kibana as a `SysV` service other than `systemd` service?